# Fusiontables: using JOIN in a query

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to query a Fusion Table using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but I can never get any data back from my joined table.

Here is my query

```
SELECT column_name_1, column_name_2, T2.other_column_name AS name
FROM table_1_id AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2_id AS T2
ON T1.id = T2.id
```

I get the results from the columns of my first table but from the columns of my joined table (`T2.other_column_name AS name`)  I get an error `Unknown column other_column_name`. I know the column name is correct.

This is an example from [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference)

```
CREATE VIEW 'Coffee Production and GDP Per Capita' AS
(SELECT 'Coffee Producing Country', Population, 'Harvesting per capita', T2.'Income group'
 FROM 1Ej110snYG9y_baaeNoZrmcAXKoTEtQVyAcY- AS T1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 1YDlqQzZHVMPxSadct1u5cBBiN341xOCMcO6kSkU AS T2
     ON T1.'Coffee Producing Country' = T2.Country)
```

The difference with my version is that Google creates a `VIEW`

Am I doing something wrong? or can we not query multiple tables without creating a `VIEW`?

Answer (score 1):

> or can we not query multiple tables without creating a VIEW?

Right. The JOIN syntax can only be used to create a merged table, not as a general query mechanism.